# Start iTunes after Network Share Mounted

Tags: itunes, network, mount

I have my iTunes library on a network volume that is mounted on startup.  I did this by dragging the volume icon into my login items.  When I restart my computer iTunes starts before the network share is mounted.

Currently iTunes appears in the login items before the network share.  Do login items get started in the order they appear?  If true if I re-add iTunes so it appears below the network share will that fix my issue?

Last resort I can create an applescript that starts at launch that will connect to thet network share and then start iTunes.

Thanks in advance, Scott

Comment: They do launch in the listed order, but that still may not be enough time for the drive to mount before iTunes wants to see it

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating an Automator application and adding the Automator app to my login items instead of iTunes and the network share.[image]